# local publish service fabric service stops my internet connection

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

Every time I publish services from service fabric in my local machine the process shut down my internet connection until it is finished. Some times this process takes 10 minutes so my computer is isolated until it finishes, once the service is published all applications reconnect and continue working normally until I publish again (no matter if I am inside the company network or at home, it is the same). This happens with any service, so it is not related to a specific one. I am publishing from Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 in a Win 7 machine.

Comment: Can you post more details of your services and how they are configured?

Comment: I would recommend opening an issue here https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/